# Product repository - get methods' store id argument = null

Tags: magento2, product, repository, store-id

If I do not provide `$storeId` argument for methods `get()` or `getById` what store id would be used? Default? Or current?

If I DO use this argument we can see that it will be set and data specific for data store will be obtained, but I don't see what will happen if no id is provided.

`public function get($sku, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false)
    {
        $cacheKey = $this->getCacheKey([$editMode, $storeId]);
        if (!isset($this->instances[$sku][$cacheKey]) || $forceReload) {
            $product = $this->productFactory->create();
            $productId = $this->resourceModel->getIdBySku($sku);
            if (!$productId) {
                throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Requested product doesn\'t exist'));
            }
            if ($editMode) {
                $product->setData('_edit_mode', true);
            }
            if ($storeId !== null) {
                $product->setData('store_id', $storeId);
            }
            $product->load($productId);
            $this->instances[$sku][$cacheKey] = $product;
            $this->instancesById[$product->getId()][$cacheKey] = $product;
        }
        return $this->instances[$sku][$cacheKey];
    }`